# Использование статических переменных в нестатических методах

Tags: c++, классы, static

Почему возникает ошибка?

```
#include <vector>

struct A {
    void foo() {
        container.resize(2);
        container[0] = constant; // тут можно использовать
        //container.push_back(constant); // а тут ошибка линковки
    }

    std::vector<int> container;
    static const int constant = 42;
};

int main(){
    A a;
    a.foo();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас все правильно написано за исключением того, что статическую переменную нужно определить вне класса, когда она, как написано в стандарте, ODR (One Definition Rule)-используется.

```
#include <vector>

struct A {
    void foo() {
        container.resize(2);
        container[0] = constant; // тут можно использовать
        //container.push_back(constant); // а тут ошибка линковки
    }

    std::vector<int> container;
    static const int constant = 42;
};

const int A::constant;

int main(){
    A a;
    a.foo();
}
```

Различие между предложениями

```
container[0] = constant; // тут можно использовать
container.push_back(constant); // а тут ошибка линковки
```

состоит в том, что во втором случае (`push_back`) берется ссылка на объект,

```
void push_back(const T& x);
                     ^^
```

а потому объект должен быть определен. То есть, чтобы было более понятно, функция `push_back` внутри своего тела имеет дело с ссылкой на объект. Код этой функции уже был скомпилирован и помещен в библиотеку задолго до компиляции вашего кода. А потому компилятор в тело этой функции не может внести никакие изменения. Раз функция имеет дело с ссылкой на объект, то объект должен быть определен.

Для первого случая это не требуется, так как компилятор просто может подставить значение константы в предложение

```
container[0] = 42; //constant;
```

на этапе компиляции определения вашего класса.

Comment: Т.е. надо ли считать, что VC++ 2015, компилируя этот код, неправ? И потом, компилятор ведь для просто числа вполне может использовать `push_back()`? Например, просто `push_back(42)`?

Comment: @Harry Просто push_back( 42) означает, что создается временный объект и на него передается ссылка. Временный объект и объект, определенный в классе, это два разных объекта.

Comment: Я понимаю, но ведь такая оптимизация в принципе допустима? Компилятор может создать временный объект, не требуя создания явного? или не имеет права?

Comment: И вот еще - http://ideone.com/MfRVFN - тут есть ссылка на такой вот `static const int` - правда, шаблонный - почему такая разница?

Comment: @Harry Такая оптимизация, строго говоря, не соответствует стандарту. То есть нарушается правило ODR, то есть что каждый объект, используемый в программе, должен быть один раз определен. В случае временных объектов компилятор при каждом вызове push_back будет их создавать, и совсем не обязательно, что адреса этих объектов будут равны между собой.

Comment: @Harry С моей точки зрения, компилятор должен выдавать диагностическое сообщение. Этот вопрос можно поднять на форуме по обсуждению стандарта C++.

Answer (score 0):

инициализируйте так

```
#include <vector>

struct A {
    void foo() {
        container.resize(2);
        //container[0] = constant; // тут можно использовать
        container.push_back(constant); // а тут ошибка линковки
    }

    std::vector<int> container;
    static const int constant;
};

const int A::constant = 42;

int main(){
    A a;
    a.foo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Значит, компилятор не в состоянии оптимизировать, и нужно определить `constant` отдельно (http://ideone.com/NTB4u8)

```
    static const int constant;
};

const int constant = 42;
```

Но, например, тот же VC++ 2015 совершенно спокойно скомпилировал и собрал исходный код.

Comment: А что тут должно оптимизироваться? Поведение `VC++2015` соответствует стандарту?

Comment: @user249988 Ну, может я не так понимаю тонкости, то например тут http://ideone.com/PjdHr1 используется `static const int`-член без определения.